# Unable to insert a row in Phoenix using a PreparedStatement

Tags: java, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am using phoenix-4.7.0-HBase-1.1-bin. I am trying to insert a row into the database by use of the `PreparedStatement` API, but no row is inserted and no exception is thrown. Here is my my sample program:

```
    import java.sql.*;

public class PhoenixExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      // create a mysql database connection
      String myDriver = "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver";
      String myUrl = "jdbc:phoenix:host:2181:/hbase";
      Class.forName(myDriver);
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "", "");

      String query = "UPSERT INTO floattest(value1, value2) values(?, ?)";

      // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
      PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
      preparedStmt.setFloat(1, 1094993918);
      preparedStmt.setFloat(2,804081421);

      // execute the preparedstatement
      boolean executed = preparedStmt.execute();
      System.out.println("EXECUTED = " + executed);
      preparedStmt.close();

      conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.err.println("Got an exception!" + e);
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Have I missed anything in statement preparation? How should I modify this to successfully insert a row?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Phoenix's SQL dialect, but it's suspicious that you are using an `UPSERT` statement (which I guess means to either 'INSERT' or 'UPDATE', depending on the supplied values) with values that do not appear to include a key.  Is it possible that you are successfully updating an existing row with the same values it already contains?  That would succeed without any observable change to the table's contents.

Comment: Just a silly question : don't you need to commit your data?

Comment: assumes AutoCommit int his case.   you probably want to post the stacktrace in this case.  I imagine it's a format problem.  `Possible values: -3.402823466 E + 38 to 3.402823466 E + 38. Mapped to java.lang.Float. The binary representation is an 4 byte float with the sign bit flipped (so that negative values sort before positive values).`. you probably want to use Float.parseFloat("YourNumber") and pass it into setFloat

Comment: @C.Champagne Compliant JDBC drivers start in auto-commit mode.

Answer (score 4):

Commit must be called after execute the prepared statement. Generally auto-commit is set to 10000 rows. Try commit preparedStatement execution

```
ps.executeUpdate();

conn.commit();
```

Comment: That would violate the JDBC requirements for auto commit. JDBC requires that in auto commit mode, after completion of a statement, it is committed.

Comment: You can disable auto-commit by writing one line of code: 
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the JDBC specification has explicit requirements for the behavior of auto commit.

Answer (score 0):

Get same result.

Actually, there're some data into the table, only the primary key.

`select * from xxx` will give empty, but `select pk from xxx` will give only PK.

This is very ridiculous, since it also checks `some column is set to varchar(10) but insert a string length=12`, but only insert the primary key.

Comment: I get an idea what's happened, the jdbc actually inserted the data, but the sqline.py client can't read it but the primary key....